# django template url tag causes maximum recursion exceeded error

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mako, django-socialauth

I am using django 1.5.1 and django social auth for my social logins. To get the facebook login url I use this

```
from django.template import Template, Context 
facebook_url = Template("{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}").render(Context())
```

Only to get error below.

```
Template error:
In template <unknown source>, error at line 1
maximum recursion depth exceeded
1 :  {% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}
```

It works fine on my production server and local dev box and the python and django and django social auth versions seem the same. I am trying to figure out if something has changed in the syntax of some library whose version that may be different on my test server.

---

TRACEBACK:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: <<MYSERVERURL>>

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'djcelery',
 'djcelery_email',
 'social_auth',
 'myapp',
 'postman',
 'storages')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'djangomako.middleware.MakoMiddleware',
 'myapp.myappmiddleware.MYAPPContextMiddleware')


Template error:
In template <unknown source>, error at line 1
   maximum recursion depth exceeded
   1 :  {% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %} 

Traceback:
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  121.                             response = middleware_method(request, e)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/ec2-user/myapppy/myapp/usercontext.py" in _wrapped_func
  282.                 return func(request, *args, **kwargs)  
File "/home/ec2-user/myapppy/myapp/pageviews.py" in usersignin
  58.         facebook_url = Template("{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'facebook' %}").render(Context())
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  411.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=context.current_app)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  496.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  382.         possibilities = self.reverse_dict.getlist(lookup_view)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  297.             self._populate()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  274.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  297.             self._populate()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  286.                 lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  230.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  29.         result = func(*args)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  97.             mod = import_module(mod_name)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/ec2-user/myapppy/postman/views.py" in <module>
  24. from postman.forms import WriteForm, AnonymousWriteForm, QuickReplyForm, FullReplyForm
File "/home/ec2-user/myapppy/postman/forms.py" in <module>
  28. class BaseWriteForm(GenericForms.ModelForm):
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documents.py" in __new__
  307.         opts = new_class._meta = ModelFormOptions(getattr(new_class, 'Meta', None))
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documents.py" in __init__
  283.             self.document._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(self.document)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()

<<<REPEATS>>>>>
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  97.                 f.document_type._meta = DocumentMetaWrapper(f.document_type)
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in __init__
  71.         self._setup_document_fields()
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongodbforms/documentoptions.py" in _setup_document_fields
  96.             if isinstance(f, ReferenceField) and not isinstance(f.document_type._meta, DocumentMetaWrapper):
File "/home/ec2-user/.virtualenvs/MYAPP/lib64/python2.7/abc.py" in __instancecheck__
  132.         if subclass is not None and subclass in cls._abc_cache:

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /signin
Exception Value: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

---

### UPDATE:

It seems like the django-postman module was causing this problem. Commenting that out got rid of this problem. Still not sure why it worked on the dev box and the production server and not on the test server. This is a temporary fix because I will be needing the django-postman module in the future but for now I have unblocked myself.

Comment: The reason I have to use this syntax is also because I am using mako templates instead of the standard django templating. This is used to get the url that the mako template can consume.

Comment: Could you post the entire traceback?

Comment: Posted it in the question. Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit did you tryed to set an higher recursion limit? the default one is rather low. Try a thousand. It's made to avoid infinite loop. You may be in one, if your'e not, it'll fix your problem.

Comment: Based on the traceback it did seem to have recursed way more than twice. I could be wrong. But I am not sure if the recursion limit is the issue...